# Connecting a JSF web application to a Mule Flow

Tags: java, jsf, client, integration, mule

I am very new to Java, JSF and Mule. My requirement is to make a web application, like a dashboard in JSF and it has to interact with a database(MSSQL) and Mule server. Pardon me, for this is a very generic question, but would be greatful if someone could give me any directions. How to connect a web application to a mule flow? how to start a mule flow writing a code in Java? Actually where to start, I have encountered words like muleclient,spring, apache CXF, but I am not sure which is relevant. Some directions and ideas on this please!

Comment: What information do you need to get from Mule? How is the Mule application you are connecting to exposing its data?

Comment: I am trying to get the concepts clear now. The scenario is, there is a mule flow, and I have a UI. I need to communicate with the database and should be able to start the mule flow from the UI, say using a button. I have chooses JSF to build the UI(don't know if it's the best option). this is my requirement. I don't know where to start and what all components I need in this design. I am sorry, this is not helping much, but like I said my experience is totally in C/c++ and PHP, and its been only 3 weeks since I started learning java and mule. any help is appreciated